# Android - How to use POST method withi @Body in retrofit 2?

Tags: android, mysql

I'm trying to insert user into MySQL database from my Android app using method post RetrofitAPI. But i got this error: **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $**. Here is my code:
File GetAPI:

```
public interface GetApi {
@POST("addmember.php")
Call<ModelInsertUser> insertUser(
        @Body ModelInsertUser modelLogin
);}
```

File ModelInsertUser:

```
public class ModelInsertUser implements Serializable {

private String ten_tv;
private String mk_tv;

public ModelInsertUser(String ten_tv, String mk_tv) {
    this.ten_tv = ten_tv;
    this.mk_tv = mk_tv;
}

public String getTen_tv() {
    return ten_tv;
}

public String getMk_tv() {
    return mk_tv;
}

public void setTen_tv(String ten_tv) {
    this.ten_tv = ten_tv;
}

public void setMk_tv(String mk_tv) {
    this.mk_tv = mk_tv;
}}
```

And my MainActivity(just have addMember method):

```
private void addMember() {
    ModelInsertUser model = new ModelInsertUser(edtUser.getText().toString(),edtPass.getText().toString());
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient().create();
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("http://192.168.1.130/database/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();
    GetApi service = retrofit.create(GetApi.class);
    Call<ModelInsertUser> call = service.insertUser(model);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ModelInsertUser>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ModelInsertUser> call, Response<ModelInsertUser> response) {
            Log.d("DEMOO","hello");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ModelInsertUser> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("DEMOO",t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

I know this error because i need a JSON object but i have String, but i don't
know where is this error. 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Create a json object from and string and pass that as body

Comment: thanks i will try this

Answer (score 1):

> try this

```
   @POST("addmember.php")
Call<JsonElement> insertUser(
        @Body ModelInsertUser modelLogin
);
```